# How to Create .cmake File

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I was working on a project which requires me to add a user.cmake file in the root directory. Can anyone help me out hot to create the .cmake file...

[Link to Project Directory](https://gitlab.com/smeeze/eego-sdk-pybind11)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are Question/Answer site, but I see no **question** in your post. Could you elaborate what functionality do you expect from `.cmake` file, what have you tried and what exactly causes the difficulty for you? You may also (re-)read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you provided `user.cmake` just needs to point where so-called eego sdk is located in your file system:

```
set(EEGO_SDK_ZIP /path/to/download/eego-sdk-1.3.19.40453.zip)
```

There is nothing fancy actually here, just make a plain text file, put this one line (don't forget to replace the `EEGO_SDK_ZIP` variable content) and save it with the name `user.cmake`

Comment: With what should i replace  EEGO_SDK_ZIP ??

Comment: so, Basically I should download the file in Zip format and create a text file in which i need to write the above snippet.

Comment: @GovindMadhav correct. You don't need to change EEGO_SDK_ZIP, it's an alias the initial Cmake file will refer to when looking for the path you provided